# Set animated UITableViewCell highlight color in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

By default the highlight effect of a `UITableViewCell` looks like this:

[image: Default highlight effect]

I'm looking for a similar effect that instead of grey is a custom color (for sake of example the `UIColor` default red value). I've tried to implement this myself using the `setHighlighted` delegate but it doesn't produce the animated effect the default style does.

This is the code I have used and the undesired effect that is achieved:

```
override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
  super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)

  if highlighted {
    self.backgroundColor = .red
  }
}
```

Alongside setting `cell.selectionStyle = .none` in `cellForRowAt`.

[image: Undesired highlight effect]

Is there any way to produce a native-like animated custom highlight color?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another condition "else" for your "if" condition and clear the red background color to normal.

```
  if highlighted {
    self.backgroundColor = .red
  }else { 
    self.backgroundColor = .white
  }
```

Comment: Hey Mina. I do know that, what I am trying to achieve is the native-like animation.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited)
You could use gestures to simulate the behaviour of the native, something like this:

```
  let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressed:")
yourCell.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

  func longPressed(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
   {
        if sender.state == .began {
            yourCell.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay:0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEeaseOut, animations: { yourCell.backgroundColor = .red })

        }
        if sender.state == .ended {
            yourCell.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay:0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEeaseOut, animations: { yourCell.backgroundColor = .white })
        }
   }
```

Comment: Hey Ahmed, this isn't the issue I'm having. I am looking to replicate the native-like animation.